# Getting GPS strength in Android

Tags: android, android-location

In my app, I have to find out GPS strength. However, when I use the following code, I get 0 only for count no of satellites. So, I could not get GPS strength.

My code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  locMgr = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
  locMgr.addGpsStatusListener(onGpsStatusChange) ;
  onGpsStatusChange.onGpsStatusChanged(GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS);                     
 // Listener for GPS Status...
}

            final Listener onGpsStatusChange=new GpsStatus.Listener()
            {       
                    public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event)
                    {
                        Log.e("gps","in class");
                            switch(event)
                            {
                             case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:
                                  GpsStatus xGpsStatus =locMgr.getGpsStatus(null) ;

                                  Iterable<GpsSatellite> iSatellites               =xGpsStatus.getSatellites();
                                  Iterator<GpsSatellite> it = iSatellites.iterator();
                                   int count=0;
                                   while(it.hasNext()){
                                    count=count+1;
                                        GpsSatellite oSat = (GpsSatellite) it.next();
                                        

                                        Log.e("gps",""+oSat.getSnr());   
                                   }
                                 Log.e("count",""+count);
                                 tv1.setText(""+count);
                             break;
                            }
                    }
            };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private class MyGPSListener implements GpsStatus.Listener {
    public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
        switch (event) {
            case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:
                if (mLastLocation != null)
                    isGPSFix = (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastLocationMillis) < 3000;

                if (isGPSFix) { // A fix has been acquired.
                    // Do something.
                } else { // The fix has been lost.
                    // Do something.
                }

                break;
            case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX:
                // Do something.
                isGPSFix = true;

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

OK, now in onLocationChanged() you should add the following:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location == null) return;
    mLastLocationMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    // Do something.
    mLastLocation = location;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get GPS signal to noise ratio of each sat from the NMEA sentances

```
 $GPGSV,2,1,08,01,40,083,46,02,17,308,41,12,07,344,39,14,22,228,45*75
```

Where:

```
      GSV          Satellites in view
      2            Number of sentences for full data
      1            sentence 1 of 2
      08           Number of satellites in view

      01           Satellite PRN number
      40           Elevation, degrees
      083          Azimuth, degrees
      46           SNR - higher is better
           for up to 4 satellites per sentence
      *75          the checksum data, always begins with *
```

To listen to NMEA data you need to create a [NMEA listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.NmeaListener.html).

Answer (score 2):

I found that the best way to obtain (and filter) the accuracy and fix location is to use the solution found at:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html#BestEstimate , and that's the BEST result I got so far.

Suppose you already have a good location and you make use of it (e.g. animateTo ..)
then let's suppose you save that location in Location variable and you call it `currentBestLocation`.

What you should do is put the `isBetterLocation()` (from "Maintaining a current best estimate"
I just posted in google site upward) method in your activity, and then when in your `onLocationChanged()`
you should send the `currentBestLocation` and the location you just got from the `onLocationChanged()` to `isBetterLocation()`
(e.g. from `onLocationChanged()` you write `isBetterLocation(location, currentBestLocation)`.

in `isBetterLocation()` it will send you back `true` if the new location is better than the last location you have  right now (the last location is `currentBestLocation`)

If it returns true, that means that the accuracy is good.. you should use that location
(don't forget to update --> `currentBestLocation = location` )

Comment: this answer seems unrelated to the question